# Way of storage of values in temporary variables in NASM

Tags: linux, nasm, x86-64

I am using a variable named "buff" that reserves 2 bytes in .bss section.
And then accepting input from user and storing this in "buff".

The user gives the input as "1" and then presses "Enter". So, 31H and "0D"(CARRIAGE RETURN) go into this variable. But how does this sequence present in the memory location named by "buff".

Is it 31 0D or 0D 31 ?

And when I write:  `mov al, byte[buff]`
then what gets inside al ? 0DH or 31H

Also, If I write: `mov rsi,[buff]`
then will rsi point to "0D" or "31" ?

I am taking input from user by:

```
    mov rax, 0
    mov rdi, 0
    mov rsi, buff
    mov rdx, 2
    syscall
```

Comment: What code you are using to receive user input and store it in buff?

Comment: NASM 64 bit programming

Comment: I am taking input from user  by :
mov rax,0
mov rdi,0
mov rsi,buff
mov rdx,2
syscall

Comment: linux OS is used

Comment: Linux normally would not store 0Dh in the buffer. On input, it normally converts carriage return to newline (0Ah).

Comment: From the title I thought this question was going to be about different ways of getting temporary storage that are better than static allocation.  e.g. use space on the stack.  The actual question asked has nothing to do with the data being temporary or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linux read system call stores characters in the buffer in the order they are read. The first character read is stored at buffer[0] and subsequent characters are stored at consecutive increasing addresses.

So, `mov al, byte[buff]` will load the first character read, which is 31h in your example.

Comment: @Jester I was told that x86 achitecture follows little endian and hence in buff enter will be stored at lower memory location and "31" at higher memory address. But, according to you it follows big endian.

Comment: If linux does not store 0DH in buff then why its size has to be taken 2 bytes

Comment: Little endian has nothing to do with storing bytes. It only affects storing things larger than one byte.

Comment: Linux normally converts carriage return to newline on input from a tty.

Comment: Well, "Enter" and "31H" together make up 2 bytes then why won't it use little endian for the storage in "buff". Also, if whatever u told is correct then for any variable storing greater than 2 bytes, it will always store value in big endian order which certainly does not make any sense !!

Comment: @Jester  Do explain this !!